# How to simulate vector sound waves in Blender?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation, scale, audio

I am making an animation where I visualize audio in the form of a vector sound wave. I am trying to make this "wave" with a line of stretched cylinders. 
[image]
The goal is to make waves that look like this
[image]
[image]
The cylinders should stay in the same place but as the sound moves through, they change scale. Is there a way to use actual sound files to simulate this, or could I and how would I do this just using the wave effect, or do I have to set scale keyframes at different points?

Comment: Look into [Blender animation nodes](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+animation+nodes+audio+visualizer). You'll be able to get what you want easily.

Comment: cant seem to download the animation nodes addon. Is there no new 2.81 build?

Comment: Just download the 2.8* daily from [here](https://animation-nodes.com/#download).